# Gradle set Gradle JVM per module

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

i have one main module which has two sub modules. The problem is that one of them is using java 1.8 and the other one is using java 1.7. 
 1. How can i add Gradle JVM to be per sub module ?
 2. Is there any property for setting java ?

I am using gradle 4.10.2

Comment: you can add sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility in your build.gradle file.

Comment: Yes, but this does not change gradle jvm and the java. They are just used to say that this should be executed wtih concrete java and if not, it fails

Comment: I am searching how to change gradle jvm to be per sub module

Answer (score 0):

You will need to decouple the JVM running Gradle from the JVM running your Java related tasks (compile, test, execute).
Once you go down that path, each sub project can be configured individually and thus use the expected JVM.

You can see an example of [doing this with Java 7](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_cross_compilation) in the documentation.

Comment: This seems to be okay, but it does not work. I set new java home and executable for compile but  when i run the command for building they are not used. 
``
tasks.withType(AbstractCompile) {
    options.with {
        fork = true
        forkOptions.javaHome = file(javaHome)
    }
}
``

Comment: Could you update with your question with what you tried? Especially how you get to determine `javaHome` and what makes you say it does not work. Thanks

Comment: I am running the command gradle clean build. I also added tests to be executed with java7. Running the command i have an error which says that the code is compiled with one java and the tests are executed with another. JAVA_HOME environment variable points to java 8. javaHome is variable which is declared in gradle.properties and points to java7 directory.

Comment: i used sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility but this is not the solution, because if the compiled java sources with java 1.7 are differents from these which are compiled with 1.8. The other solution that you propose does not work, because the java cannot be changed after initialization